# Cross Browser Addons

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, browser, firefox-addon, google-chrome

I'm looking to make a browser add-on as widely and easily distributed as possible.

Is there a set of wrapper add-ons for all of the major browsers, that will let me write one piece of code which can then be executed in any of the major browsers? I don't need anything fancy, just DOM and some ajax stuff.

Something along the lines of greasemonkey for IE, FF, and Chrome would be nice.

In the same vein, is there a way to link to my script so that it prompts for an install of greasemonkey (if it isn't installed), and then leads the script?

Comment: Are you developing a content plug-in (like Flash) or a Browser-level plug-in (like FlashBlock)?

Comment: Browser-level. Hopefully in Javascsript but I'm open to others (XUL) if needed.

Answer (score 1):

For IE there's [Trixie](http://www.bhelpuri.net/Trixie/) or [IE7Pro](http://www.ie7pro.com/), there's built-in [Opera support for userscripts](http://my.opera.com/Contrid/blog/2007/02/11/how-to-greasemonkey-in-opera), and for Safari there's [GreaseKit](http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/11/14/how-to-run-greasemonkey-scripts-in-safari/), and for Chrome, you can [enable user-scripts](http://www.chromeplugins.org/google/chrome-talk/userscripts-chrome-7483.html) as well.

I'm not sure about auto-triggering the install of GreaseMonkey.

Comment: Wow, ok. Any scripts to do browser detection and get my users to install the right one? And any documentation on the shared subset of available features?

Comment: For browser detection, I'd use jQuery.browser (http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.browser), or you could try to parse navigator.userAgent (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp) yourself.

The QuirksMode compatibility charts (http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html) are a good source of what features of JS (and other things) are supported in various browsers.